# Why do weeping angels have pointy teeth?

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

In *Doctor Who*, we see that normally weeping angels cover their eyes:

[image: Weeping angel covering it's eyes]

When a weeping angel is attacking someone, it uncovers it's face and bares it's fangs:

[image: Weeping angel with fangs]

If weeping angels feed off of people's "remaining time energy of the victim's life" [wikia](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Weeping_Angel), why do they need fangs? Wouldn't a creature only need sharp teeth if it needed to tear through meat? I understand that the writers wanted the weeping angels to be scary, but is there an in universe explanation?

Comment: Bacon.­­­­­­­­­

Comment: Maybe, we don't know everything about them. Ever wondered how they fight with each other?

Comment: All the better to eat you with

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The Weeping Angels had a unique and nearly perfect defense mechanism: quantum-locking, which caused them to turn into harmless stone when being observed. <sub>- [source](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Weeping_Angel)</sub>

Since their transformation into stone is a *defense mechanism*, it is likely that the sharp teeth are simply part of this defense mechanism as their prey would be frightened by such a sight and therefore be less likely to attack.

We all know they cover their faces to avoid trapping each other in petrified form by looking at one another. Notice that covering their face *initially* also gives them a non-threatening appearance. However, if they're threatened or they're hunting prey and the prey looks at them, they assume a scary appearance while quantum-locked as a defense mechanism. Also, something frightening and scary is more likely to make you look away or blink, allowing the Weeping Angels to advance.

Many real life creatures put on a scary display to frighten predators. For example, the Owl Butterfly mimics the scary face of an owl (even though the butterfly is much less powerful than an owl):

[image]

Comment: Worth noting, I think the Weeping Angels cover their faces to prevent looking into the eyes of another Weeping Angel, and therefore becoming permanently locked in place alongside the other angel. I don't think it has anything to with looking less threatening.

Comment: @theik pretty sure that's stated in one of the weeping angel episodes

Comment: Agreed @Theik http://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Gjv.jpg  that's how Sally Sparrow escaped

Comment: Something frightening and scary is likely to make you look away or blink, which means... The Weeping Angels get to advance upon you.

Comment: @CreationEdge good point, I'll add that in. Thanks. :)

Comment: @CreationEdge If I saw something frightening and scary closing in on me, I'd want to keep an eye on it.

Comment: @randal'thor That's a good point. According to the show Brain Games, we pay more attention to dangerous things. [see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UpfK9kRDnJE&t=2m50s)

Comment: @randal'thor You'd want to, doesn't mean you would. People often blink in surprise or shock, or look around to assess further danger. Plus, if a statue is moving (what!?), you'd likely look around to see if you're just crazy. Or, your flight response goes on and you turn and run away. My point is, there are a lot of normal reactions that aren't "Stare this thing that shouldn't exist in the face") ;)